# Pass Captured Image to JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html

The input element in the following snippet puts a browse button in an HTML page. When the page is accessed from an Android device, it shows a browse button which opens my camera and selects the captured image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, how can I pass the selected image to a JavaScript function to run any logic on it?

Comment: This code is not enough to fully understand your problem

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: This is a site with people trying to help. Being unfriendly will not help you here. Anyhow, I wish you good luck!

Comment: @gilbert-v the answer there is using jquery which I wouldn't prefer using.

Comment: Then I'm sorry. I saw the comment and just saw you added some basic HTML. So I thought you were just being sarcastic by asking: "Is it more clear now?" My mistake.

Comment: @AhmedTawila see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to append more info to your question, but if you have use some techniques to make the `input` hold your image source uri, then you can get the value via:

```
<input id="image-input" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />

// js:
const input = document.querySelector("#image-input")
input.addEventListener('change', _ => {
  // if you want to read the image content
  const reader = new window.FileReader()
  // input.files[0] is the first image, you may want to directly use it instead of read it
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
  // reader.result is the image content in base64 format
  reader.addEventListener('load', _ => console.log(reader.result))

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's translate the jQuery from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) to your preferred native JavaScript.

```
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result); becomes...
      document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

//$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  //readURL(this);
//}); becomes...
document.getElementById("imgInp").onchange = function() {
  readURL(this)
}
```